# VBA: Using a range returned from a function

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to use WorksheetFunction.Match in VBA, but I'm having issues in populating the lookup_array parameter. For the lookup_array, I'm using the output of another function -GetSubRange() as Range - that returns a range.
I've verified that my WorksheetFunction.Match() syntax works, and that my GetSubRange() function also works - when coded differently, I can get the address, select it, etc.

The result is that the function returns a #VALUE! error, which I've concluded is that the lookup_array parameter isn't referencing the range input properly.

Any ideas?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Function GetValue(rng As Range, colName As String, key As String) As String
    Dim rngSubRange As Range
    Set rngSubRange = GetSubRange(rng, colName)
    GetValue = WorksheetFunction.Match(key, rngSubRange, 0)
End Function

Function GetSubRange(rng As Range, colName As String) As Range
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim colNum As Integer

    Set rngHeader = ThisWorkbook.Names(rng.Name.Name &"_Header").RefersToRange
    colNum = Application.Match(colName, rngHeader, 0)

    Set GetSubRange = rng.Columns(colNum)
 End Function
```

Comment: You could make a global variable and store the array in the global variable, allowing you to call it from every subroutine.  Just make sure that the final subroutine includes a dump of the global information or it can get interesting for you.

Comment: I tested a simplified version of your code. The 3rd arg in `Match` is `0`, which means **exact match**. If there's no exact match in `rngSubRange` you'll get a `#VALUE!` error. When I switched the 3rd arg to `1` my function returned w/o error. Side point: `Match` will return the **index** of the matching value (an integer); you're using `String` which may not be appropriate.

Comment: @Cyril, unfortunately, I'd like to avoid the messiness of global variables. I intentionally used this as a function so that it can be used in formulas across the entire workbook.

Comment: @xidgel, good catch on the mismatching data types. Unfortunately, I was pretty sure that wasn't it. Instead of using my GetSubRange UDF, I tested out the function by hardcoding the range, which got the function working as intended. I did this with the exact match, which was intentional. I'm just working on getting it a bit more dynamic.

Comment: So it works when you hard code the subrange, but not when you compute it? Maybe try adding some debug code to verify that the correct subrange is generated, e.g., debug.print the number of rows and columns, the address, the first element, etc. before the call to WorksheetFunction.Match

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the algorithm: I was searching in the wrong subrange. rngSubRange was getting the range of the value column, but the key was in another column. I had to create to subranges: one for the key column and one for the value column.